# Getting 11.0 as output data for all the scans when using pointcloud_to_laserscan node

Tags: ros, pointcloud-to-laserscan, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a bunch of pointcloud which i need to convert to laserscan. The data i have are in pointcloud and cannot be used directly. So i converted them to pointcloud2 using the point_cloud_converter and fed the pointcloud2 data to the CloudTOScan Nodelet. However the resulting published data is 11.0 for all the scans which corresponds to range_max + 1.0. I tried verifying the input data. Both the pointcloud and the converted pointcloud2 data can be viewed correctly in rviz. Any idea on what might be causing the issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10884/getting-11.0-as-output-data-for-all-the-scans-when-using-pointcloud_to_laserscan-node/) by [Zack](https://answers.ros.org/users/949/zack/) on ROS Answers with karma: 216 on 2011-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems like it's because the pointclouds i have are assembled from a tilting laser scanner instead of a kinect camera. Therefore the direction conventions are different. I edited the direction conventions in the pointcloud_to_laserscan node and the laserscan are now published correctly.

---

Originally posted by [Zack](https://answers.ros.org/users/949/zack/) with karma: 216 on 2011-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [boottp](https://answers.ros.org/users/8226/boottp/) on 2013-10-28**:
I think to have the same problem.  where do you change direction conventions in pointcloud node ?